# Does Quick Edit function work for embedded entities?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view which creates a block of User data related to the author of the node. The view display is a view mode of the User entity.

I see my entity when the block is placed on the node page; but there is no quick edit functionality. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It does work, for Nodes, when set to `Show: Content | Full Content`.

However, it does not work for Users. Fairly expected as when you go to a user page, ex: */user/1* there is no quick edit feature there to begin with.